# Google-GeoCoder or Google-DistanceMatrix ....... which is better to use ? and why?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am new to Android & I am learning how to use `Geocoder`

**What i have done**::

- I did some R&D in Internet, My observation is GeoCoder uses MAP-API
- it has some functions to give the information details of the place
  like Place, streetName etc
- I came across something called Google distance matrix
- Using that also we can fetch the information regarding place but
  looks like it has only 1500 req/day free else more we have to pay

**My Questions**::

- Can GeoCoder fetch me location details if i don't use MAP-API in my
  mobile ?
- Can geocoder fetch location information directly from internet ?
- Which one is better to use Distance matrix or Geocoder ? ... if
  either one .... why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which one is better to use Distance matrix or Geocoder ?

The Geocoder and the Distance Matrix API are for different use cases.

With the [android.location.Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) you will get the coordinates for a specific street name f.e. If you provide the city/street name/administrative areas etc. it will responde a pair of latitude and longitude. This is also possible for the other way around called reverse geocoding. If you provide the latitude and longitude it will responde the fitting street name.

The [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) will responde the duration and the distance to reach a destination from an origin. To be exact, this API will take multiple origins and destinations and computes the distance and duraton for them.

> Can GeoCoder fetch me location details if i don't use MAP-API in my
>   mobile ?

The Geocoder is part of the `android.location` package, hence you don't need the `com.google.android.gms.maps` library.

> Can geocoder fetch location information directly from internet ?

Yes, but you have to use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en). The Geocoder from the SDK is communicating directly with Google Services.